# PIP doesn't install packages

Tags: python, pip

I use "pip install pyenv-win" and there are no errors but then pyenv doesn't work, I can't find it anywhere also.
I tried reinstalling pip and python

Comment: Can you please show the commands you are using? For both install and import `pyenv-win`. And also which SO you are using

Answer (score 1):

I have not had success using pyenv-win.  In contrast, I very much like pyenv on linux and mac.  I assume you would like to manage multiple versions of Python on your Windows machine.  I would suggest using anaconda instead https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [oficial documentation of pyenv-win](https://pypi.org/project/pyenv-win/1.1.2/#installation). There are 3 different ways you can install it. But on windows you need to configure your environment variable, as described in documentation.